# Akka actors always times out waiting for future

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have the following actor as defined below meant to "login" a user.

```
object AuthenticationActor {
  def props = Props[AuthenticationActor]

  case class LoginUser(id: UUID)
}

class AuthenticationActor @Inject()(cache: CacheApi, userService: UserService) extends Actor{
  import AuthenticationActor._

  def receive = {
    case LoginEmployee(id: UUID) => {
      userService.getUserById(id).foreach {
        case Some(e) => {
          println("Logged user in")
          val sessionId = UUID.randomUUID()
          cache.set(sessionId.toString, e)
          sender() ! Some(e, sessionId)
        }
        case None => println("No user was found")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: `userService.getUserById` returns a `Future[Option[User]]`

And the following very simplistic API cal to it

```
class EmployeeController @Inject()(@Named("authentication-actor") authActor: ActorRef)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) extends Controller {

  override implicit val timeout: Timeout = 5.seconds

  def login(id: UUID) = Action.async { implicit request =>
    (authActor ? LoginUser(id)).mapTo[Option[(User, UUID)]].map {
      case Some(authInfo) =>   Ok("Authenticated").withSession(request.session + ("auth" -> authInfo._2.toString))
      case None => Forbidden("Not Authenticated")
    }
  }
}
```

Both `println` calls will execute, but `login` call will always fail saying that the ask has time out.  Any suggestions?

Comment: shouldn't you use pipeTo i/o mapTo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do such thing (accessing sender within `Future`s callback) you need to store `sender` in a `val` in outter scope when you receive request because it is very likely change before `Future` completes.

```
def receive = {
    case LoginEmployee(id: UUID) => {
      val recipient = sender

      userService.getUserById(id).foreach {
        case Some(e) => {
          ...
          recipient ! Some(e, sessionId)
        }
        ...
      }
    }
  }
```

You also never send a result when user wasn't found.

What you actually should do here is pipe the `Future` result to the `sender`

```
def receive = {
  case LoginEmployee(id: UUID) => {
    userService.getUserById(id) map { _.map { e =>
        val sessionId = UUID.randomUUID()
        cache.set(sessionId.toString, e)
        (e, sessionId)
      }
    } pipeTo sender
  }
}
```

or with prints

```
def receive = {
  case LoginEmployee(id: UUID) => {
    userService.getUserById(id) map { 
      case Some(e) =>
        println("logged user in")
        val sessionId = UUID.randomUUID()
        cache.set(sessionId.toString, e)
        Some(e, sessionId)
      case None =>
        println("user not found")
        None
    } pipeTo sender
  }
}
```

Comment: In your first example, I think `val recipient = sender` should be `val recipient = sender()` (note the parentheses).

Comment: Scala allows to omit the parenthesis for 0-arity methods, see: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/method-invocation.html

Comment: My apologies - I could have sworn I just read somewhere that it was bad practice (or even incorrect) to do this, but I can't find the reference anymore.  Must have misread.